# How we can Export Grid data to pdf in Extjs without using serverside language

Tags: pdf, extjs

I am using Extjs4.2.2 version. 
I have checked all the possible ways to find out export grid data into PDF.
i can try this exporter plugin. https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter .
but this for Excel functionality, any other PDF plugin is available, 
i am not using other language like java, PHP, net...
It's possible to export grid data into PDF(without send data to Server side) if yes means please pass the correct answer.

Comment: Would printing it in html would be an acceptable work around ? Loaine has a kickass UX.(ready for printing)

Answer (score -1):

There is no ready solution available for this in extjs.

But you may take some pointers from [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

Hopefully this will help!

Comment: This is a pdf viewer as stated in the first line of the project description on git `PDF.js is Portable Document Format (PDF) viewer that is built with HTML5.`